# In C++, can I create a thread and save it as a class member variable so it can be joined automatically in the destructor?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a c++ program in which I want to be able to call a member function which will start a separate thread. When I detach the thread, it works fine, but then I have no way to join it, so I want to store the thread as a member variable and join it automatically in the destructor.

I thought that's what the following code would do, however, I get the output shown below instead, which leads me to believe the thread is never joined. How do I join a thread saved as a member variable with a member function?

Please advise!

```
// thread example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void foo(int i) 
{
    while(true){
        cout << "Foo checkin" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
    }
}

class ThreadHolder{
    public:
        ThreadHolder(int in){i = in;};
        int i;
        void start_threads(){
            t = thread(foo, i);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()

            std::cout << "foo started\n";
            return;
        }
        ~ThreadHolder();
    private:
        thread t;
};

ThreadHolder::~ThreadHolder(){
    if (t.joinable()){
        cout << "in dest\n";
        t.join();
        cout << "joined\n";
    }
}



int main() 
{
    cout << "in main" << endl;
    ThreadHolder th(1);
    th.start_threads();
    cout << "back in main" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
in main
foo started
back in main
in dest
Foo checkin
Foo checkin
Foo checkin
Foo checkin
Foo checkin
Foo checkin
```

Comment: You need some way to tell the loop in `foo` to stop.  There are many ways to do that so you'll have to pick the way you like best.  A simple `std::atomic<bool>` could be shred between the function and the class to tell the loop when to stop.

Comment: How do you expect to join a thread that never terminates? Only threads that terminate can be joined, and whether the `std::thread` is a class member, or not, is not a factor.

Comment: A `std::thread` is an object that *represents* a single thread of execution.  It refers to the thread state.  But the important thing to remember is the `std::thread` object is **not** itself *the thread*.  Much like how a `std::fstream` object is not, itself, *the actual file* that resides on disk.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am more of a c programmer than c++. What is the advantage of an atomic bool versus say a standard boolean if only main will write to it and the foo thread will only read (rather than also writing which in my mind would require a mutex or something)

Comment: @qwerasdfzxcv Doing that introduces the data race, which is undefined behavior.  C++ requires that if you have a variables shared between threads, and at least one of those threads is a writer, then you need synchronization around that variable.  To not do so is to have a data race.  That means you need an atomic variable, a mutex around a non-atomic variables, a condition variable or some other approved synchronization method.  Do note that `volatile` is not a valid thread synchronization technique.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Re, "Only threads that terminate can be joined." That's kind of ambiguous IMO. What would `t.joinable()` return? There's a difference between saying that join() never returns and saying that join() throws an exception.

Comment: 'but then I have no way to join it'....is that some kind of problem?  Sounds like a blessing to me:)

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::jthread` to get even more:

```
class ThreadHolder{
public:
    ThreadHolder(int in): i{in} {};
    int i;
    //The stop request function:
    void stop_thread() {t.request_stop();};
    void start_thread(){
        t = jthread{[&,this](std::stop_token token){
            while(!token.stop_requested()){
                //...repeated logic
                bar(this->i);
            };
        }};
        std::cout << "foo started\n";
        return;
    };
    //Rule of 0: no copy/move/dtor:
    //~ThreadHolder();
private:
    std::jthread t;
};
```

The destructor for `std::jthread` automatically `join`s a standard mechanism is provided to notify the worker thread to stop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() 
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << "in main" std::endl;
    ThreadHolder th(1);
    th.start_thread();
    std::cout << "back in main" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
    std::cout << "notify the worker to stop" << std::endl;
    th.stop_thread();
    std::cout << "waiting for worker to stop" << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

remember that the worker function (lambda in my first snippet) must frequently check the `std::stop_token` for a stop request, or the program may continue indefinitely (until the worker thread finishes). If you do not plan to wait for the finish, you can `detach` the thread; but that would terminate the worker upon return from main and might leak resources aquired by the worker function.

Comment: Note that `std::jthread` is new for C++20.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I know. I am waiting for a complain from the OP. Because there are a variety of available solutions, in case this is actually what he needs but misses.